# Do we use Gamma Mixture Model (GMM) for data clustering in machine learning so often?

Tags: machine-learning, probability

I am coming from a machine learning background I have followed few courses on the internet too. But I have never heard much about or never met this even in a course I did. What are they actually ? Can anyone give me a simple idea. I know they are probabilistic module more of generative algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I have used Gaussian Mixture Models very often. Gamma Mixture Models is the same but using Gamma distributions instead of gaussians.

Every algorithm of mixture models is used to obtain the probability funcition of a random variable.
Instead of supposing a sinple distribution, for example a gaussian distribution:
p(x)=G(mean, variance)

They suppose a more general model, in the case of  gaussian mixture models you assume that your data are generated by a combination of simple distributions, for example:

p(x)=G(mean1,variance1)+G(mean2,variance2)+...+G(meanN,varianceN)

The gaussian mixture models algorithm obtains the values of mean1, ..., meanN and variance1, ..., varianceN

Comment: Once you have the distribution you have algorithms to obtain new samples from them (generative models)